# MvxBind Error: "Null object can not be converted to a value type" thrown before the first screen is displayed

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross to bind data from the ViewModel to properties in an axml layout file.  These bindings work correctly once the application has fully loaded.  However, there are a large number of "MvxBind:Error" messages, in the debug output log, that say "Null object can not be converted to a value type".  All of these errors occur before the android app displays the initial "SplashScreen.axml" view.  After that point, all the bindings work as expected.

It is also worth noting that these errors only occur when binding values to a property in a custom control or binding values that are passed through a custom converter.  I didn't see any issues with, for example, binding a string to the Text property in a TextView.

Sample log output of the error:

```
MvxBind:Error: 17.76 Problem seen during binding execution for from LocationCurrentMovementViewModel.IsAlarmSignaled to Visibility - problem InvalidCastException: Null object can not be converted to a value type.
07-17 20:05:51.980 I/mono-stdout( 3056): MvxBind:Error: 17.76 Problem seen during binding execution for from LocationCurrentMovementViewModel.IsAlarmSignaled to Visibility - problem InvalidCastException: Null object can not be converted to a value type.
07-17 20:05:51.980 I/mono-stdout( 3056):      at System.Convert.ToType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider, Boolean try_target_to_type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-17 20:05:51.990 I/mono-stdout( 3056):   at System.Convert.ChangeType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-17 20:05:51.990 I/mono-stdout( 3056):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.ExtensionMethods.MvxTypeExtensions.MakeSafeValue (System.Type propertyType, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-17 20:05:51.990 I/mono-stdout( 3056):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.MakeSafeValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Convert.ToType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider, Boolean try_target_to_type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Convert.ChangeType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.ExtensionMethods.MvxTypeExtensions.MakeSafeValue (System.Type propertyType, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.MakeSafeValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-17 20:05:51.990 I/mono-stdout( 3056):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[0:] MvxBind:Error: 17.76 Problem seen during binding execution for from LocationCurrentMovementViewModel.IsAlarmSignaled to Visibility - problem InvalidCastException: Null object can not be converted to a value type.
      at System.Convert.ToType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider, Boolean try_target_to_type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Convert.ChangeType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.ExtensionMethods.MvxTypeExtensions.MakeSafeValue (System.Type propertyType, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.MakeSafeValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-17 20:05:51.990 I/mono-stdout( 3056):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is the binding that is throwing that particular error:

```
<FrameLayout
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="317dp"
    p1:layout_height="360dp"
    p1:id="@+id/MovementAlertOverlay"
    p1:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="639dp"
    p1:background="@drawable/alert_border"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility LocationCurrentMovementViewModel.IsAlarmSignaled,Converter=BoolToViewStates"
 />
```

Code for the converter:

```
public class BoolToViewStatesValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, ViewStates>
{
    protected override ViewStates Convert(bool value, System.Type targetType, object parameter,
                                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            return ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        return ViewStates.Gone;
    }
}
```

I've tried checking "value" in the converter to see if it is null before returning anything.  I've also tried initializing "LocationCurrentMovementViewModel.IsAlarmSignaled" to a default value.  This has no effect on the errors that are displayed.

The object "LocationCurrentMovementViewModel" is nested within the ViewModel associated with the axml layout file.  It is set dynamically at runtime.  However, I verified this is not the cause of the issue.  I created a temp object, "TempBoolTrue, which is just a boolean variable set to true. I used that to replace "LocationCurrentMovementViewModel.IsAlarmSignaled" in the axml layout file.  This only resulted in a similar error with "TempBoolTrue" in the place of "LocationCurrentMovementViewModel.IsAlarmSignaled".

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with solving this issue.

Thanks!

---- EDIT ----

I recently started working on this project.  So, I wasn’t around when it was originally setup.  There were a couple issues that came to light.

1. The MvvmCross resources were manually added.  They are now added using nuget and at the correct version, 3.0.9.
2. I also discovered that SplashScreen.cs had been removed.  A custom version of SplashScreen.axml is being called later in the startup process.
3. The Android app starts in an irregular way.  It appears there were originally good reasons for starting the app this way; however, the resulting solution may need to change a bit.

It will take some time to sort through the rest of this.  But, your post did help me discover the source of the issue.  Thanks Stuart!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of this occurring

> before the android app displays the initial "SplashScreen.axml" view.

is slightly alarming - as the splashscreen is generally displayed before most of MvvmCross, including the binding system, is bootstrapped.

---

Reading through the description, I've no idea what the issue is. Really not sure how you are getting binding errors before the splash screen is shown.

It's probably related to the `MakeSafeValue` type conversion - but I "believe" that this can correctly handle conversion from `Null` for enum values - see the test case on [MakeSafeValueTest.cs#L98](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Test/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Test/ExtensionMethods/MakeSafeValueTest.cs#L98)

To debug this, I'd recommend:

1. Ensure you are working with the very latest MvvmCross releases (3.0.9 on nuget, July 13th on Mvvmcross-Binaries, or tagged 3.0.9 on MvvmCross repo)
2. Try creating a new simple project/solution and see if you can recreate the problem there (it genuinely only takes 1 minute to create a new core and droid project for testing)
3. If no solution presents itself during debugging, then you can raise an issue on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/new and you can push your test repo to GitHub to assist with the debugging.